# Amazon Elastic Map Reduce : Command Line Tools installation Issue?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, cloudera, elastic-map-reduce, ganglia

I'm new to Amazon web services, I'm trying to run job flows on Amazon elastic map reduce jobs using command line interface tools.

I followed the steps from amazon developer guide of this [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-cli-install.html) from aws.But things are not getting clear to me.

If I execute the command to list the job flows.  Shows the Following error.

```
:~/Applications/elastic-mapreduce-ruby$ elastic-mapreduce --list
Error: Request has expired. Timestamp date: 2013-07-09T01:13:42-07:00
```

Thanks in Advance, and Can anyone Please tell me Why i am getting the above error while listing the job flows.

Comment: Are you sure you've configured the credentials and region correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your response @SNeumann, Yes I have set the credentials properly, 

I have two doubts,
- can we use ruby 1.9.3 to use AWS command line tools for elastic map reduce. 
- I want to know, Is Access-id and secret-key is common to all the users under the particular Account, or Is it different for each users in an account.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure which Ruby version works with the EMR APIs. As for Access/secret keys - you have a pair for the account and you can set up users with Access and secret keys using IAM (Identity and Access Management) and give them proper permissions.

Comment: When I try access the security credentials option from my account, that shows Permission Denied, The Admin created my account as a user and gave me the access-id and secret-key, Is it possible to use those access-id and secret-key to create instance via command line.

Comment: It depends on the permissions that he gave your user...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem mostly occurred because of time stamp in the elastic map reduce and your computer is not same. So check the time stamp of both the machines and set the same Time stamps to the machines what u use to run your job flows. Then it would run correctly.

Comment: Long time but i tried this answer, yes after i corrected the time stamp this worked for me.